# Error with rhc-create-domain (Openshitft)

Tags: ruby, jboss, openshift, openshift-client-tools

Hi i have an error when i run the command rhc-create-domain in Ubuntu 11.10.
I follow the steps of this:

[Error with rhc-create-domain on command line (Openshitft)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260053/error-with-rhc-create-domain-on-command-line-openshitft)

But I take this error:

```
mastervodoo@vodoo:/boot/grub$ rhc domain create -n projveh -l xxxxx@gmail.com 
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/mime-types-1.18.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-03-21 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/mime-types-1.18.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-03-21 00:00:00.000000000Z"
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- mime/types (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:2
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:13
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/rest-client.rb:2
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.92.11/lib/rhc-rest.rb:2
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.92.11/lib/rhc-common.rb:12
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.92.11/bin/rhc-domain:2
from /usr/local/bin/rhc-domain:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/rhc-domain:19
```

I need `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- mime/types but how or where i can install or fix this?, thnks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I resolve this with a simple solution. Gemspecs have some different date formats that don’t validate. 
I run this command:

$ sudo sed -i 's/ 00:00:00.000000000Z//' /var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/*

and then I can run the command

$ rhc domain create
thkns.